# How to display list from array with audio duration

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to display list of all songs saved in array. I need to get audio duration for each list element. Can I do it automatically or do I have to add duration to the array myself?

```
let tracks = [
  {
    name: "Song 1",
    artist: "Monica",
    path: "..song1.mp3",
  },
  {
    name: "Song 2",
    artist: "Carol",
    path: "..song2.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Song 3",
    artist: "Sam",
    path: "..song3.mp3"
  },
];

let list = "<ul>";
for (let i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
    list += '<li>';
    list += '<div class="name">' + tracks[i].name + '</div>';
    list += '<div class="artist">' + tracks[i].artist + '</div>';
    list += '<div class="duration">XX:XX</div>';
    list += '<a href="' + tracks[i].path + '">Download</a>';
    list += '</li>';
}
let list = "</ul>";

playlist.innerHTML = list;
```

Comment: Those paths don't seem valid; I would think they'd need to be "../songN.mp3". In any case, JavaScript has no idea what that path points to. It could point to a PDF for all it knows, so no, it can't get that information "automatically". You'll need to load them using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) to get the duration.

Comment: Instead of using the audio API as @HereticMonkey suggested, you could load the media tags of the file, using a package of some sort (e.g. https://github.com/aadsm/jsmediatags). This however requires your website visitors to download the whole file. If you just need it for the duration, using the Web Audio API might be better after all. And if your files are static, i'd rather hardcode the duration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add audio element to get the duration and make this element as hidden if you don't want to display it.

You can also use any plugin if you needed.

```js
let tracks = [{
    name: "Song 1",
    artist: "Monica",
    path: "https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-3s.mp3",
  },
  {
    name: "Song 2",
    artist: "Carol",
    path: "https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-6s.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Song 3",
    artist: "Sam",
    path: "https://download.samplelib.com/mp3/sample-9s.mp3"
  },
];

function getDuration() {
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName('AUDIO');
  for (let i = 0; i < audio.length; i++) {
    let duration = document.querySelector('[id="myAudio' + i + '"]').duration;
    console.log(duration);
    document.getElementById("duration" + i).innerHTML = duration;
  }
}

let list = "<ul>";
for (let i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
  list += '<li>';
  list += '<div class="name">' + tracks[i].name + '</div>';
  list += '<div class="artist">' + tracks[i].artist + '</div>';
  list += '<div id="duration' + i + '" class="duration">00:00</div>';
  list += '<a href="' + tracks[i].path + '">Download</a>';

  // you need to add hidden audio element to get the duration 
  list += '<audio hidden id="myAudio' + i + '"  controls><source src="' + tracks[i].path + '" type="audio/mpeg">  Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>'
  list += '</li>';
}
list += "</ul>";
var playlist = document.getElementById("playListDiv");
playlist.innerHTML = list;

// get duration after the html is loaded
setTimeout(function() {
  getDuration();
}, 1000);
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="playListDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also add duration in array to avoid extra Audio element

Comment: You'd likely want to use the [`loadedmetadata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadedmetadata_event) event rather than waiting a second for the audio to load (i.e. guessing that's how long it will take the `audio` elements to load).